# Which library to use for Weak references

Tags: rust

I realize things are still in flux, but why is `Weak` referenced in 2 different places in the documentation?

`std::rc::Weak` - http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Weak.html

`alloc::rc::Weak` - http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/alloc/rc/struct.Weak.html

Maybe I'm missing something, but the only difference I see in the two is the fmt function signatures:

```
impl<T> Debug for Weak<T> where T: Debug
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error>
```

vs

```
impl<T: Debug> Debug for Weak<T>
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result
```

So which one should I use? They're both marked as "unstable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust's standard library is actually made up of multiple, interconnected crates.  `std`, aside from containing some of its own functionality, acts as a "facade" over these other crates, publicly re-exporting the bits that have been stabilised.

There is, in fact, only one `Weak`: the one in `alloc`.  It's just that `std` re-exports it.  As for which one to use: if something is available through `std`, use it through `std`: that's the path that's unlikely to change...

...except when it comes to unstable features, of which `Weak` is one: it's unstable, so there are no guarantees.

Comment: Another difference between the `std` façade and the other crates it sources things from is that `std` has been mostly stabilised, but the other crates are unstable.

Comment: @DK. while I'm **very** new to rust, I understand what you're saying... but this naturally leads to the next question, why? Why are things re-exported? Doesn't that naturally lead to confusion (mine at least) as to which to use?

Comment: @wspeirs Not once someone says "just use the version in `std`".  It's re-exported because it is **only** `std` that's been stabilised.  The other crates are more or less an implementation detail that you're not supposed to depend on.